# How to install livewallpaper on ubuntu saucy 13.10?

Tags: 13.10, desktop-background

How do I install livewallpaper on 13.10.

I tried youtube video and also tried the formula,

It seems Ubuntu 13.10 can't get the update for live wallpaper "unable to find the packages".

Answer (score 3):

Slidewall is a program that can make a slideshow wallpaper. To install:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/apps
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install slidewall
```

This application allows you to do that, for more information [see this](http://www.noobslab.com/2014/01/slidewall-live-wallpaper-application.html)